# Security vulnerabilities from storing anti CSRF token in global JS variable?

Tags: web-application, javascript, csrf

What are the security vulnerabilities arising from storing anti CSRF token as a global JS variable and use it for every requests made which need CSRF protection?

If there are any vulnerabilities what are they?
Is stealing this token made easier just because it is stored in global JS variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this approach works. Usually you'd store it in local storage even for a single-page app, so that you still have it if the user forces a top-level navigation or reloads the page, but in general it's fine.

The only danger from storing a secret in JS is that a malicious script, such as one injected by XSS, could steal it. However, that's irrelevant; XSS strictly dominates CSRF in terms of what you can do with it. Furthermore, it's impossible to avoid this risk for anti-CSRF tokens anyhow (this is *part* of why XSS dominates CSRF; once the script is running in the user's session, it can do anything that legitimate script could do, including submit requests with whatever secrets are needed).

There *is* a way (a family of them, really) to avoid needing anti-CSRF secrets at all, though. They all operate on the principle of "require script-initiated requests from a trusted domain only".

The simplest one is to pass the authentication token (a.k.a. session token or access token) in something other than a cookie (or HTTP Basic auth, or anything else that sends automatically). If the attacker doesn't have your credentials or token, they can't make your browser send requests pretending they're from you; if the attacker does have your creds or token, they don't need your browser at all. The simplest approach does have the risk that it can turn XSS into persistent session takeover (attacker steals the token), but there are mitigations for that (though they basically boil down to what you're describing here: two linked tokens, one in an HttpOnly cookie and one in the request body or similar) and it's hardly as if that's the only harm possible with XSS anyhow.

More complicated approaches rely on the fact that CORS requests - other than "simple" ones that could have, in theory, been made by an HTML form submission - trigger a "pre-flight" request. If the server rejects this pre-flight request when coming from untrusted origins (such as attacker-controlled sites that are trying to make your browser send a cross-site forged request) - as it absolutely should - then the browser won't send the actual request. There's a bunch of ways to make requests non-simple, such as adding a custom header (the value doesn't matter), using a content-type other than the ones forms support (`application/json` is common), using a method/verb other than GET and POST (e.g. PUT/PATCH/DELETE), and so on. Note that the server does need to *verify* that the request contains the needs-a-preflight content; it doesn't work, for example, to simply require that the request body be JSON, you must actually require that the content type header start with `application/json` (if you want to use that specific approach). These approaches have the advantage of stateless CSRF protection (without the issues of double-submit cookies); there's one less thing to generate, store, and check, keeping session sizes small and request processing fast.

Answer (score 0):

Storing CSRF tokens in global JS variables is not a security issue. If the attacker can read JS variables they are probably leveraging some sort of XSS exploit. In that case, there is no way for you to keep the CSRF token away from the attacker, and the attacker doesn't need it anyway since they already have XSS.

You still need to make sure you follow best practieses for whatever CSRF protection pattern you are using, i.e. use sufficiently random and unique tokens, etc.

(Many programmers would argue that global variables is a bad programming practice. But that is a separate issue.)